# Cannot find image on angular2

Tags: angular

I am building a new application on angular 2 and it was working perfectly when I used the command (ng serve) from angular-cli. However, when I tried to put the application on a tomcat server with the command (ng build or ng build --prod) it did not recognize some of my images. It was not all of them, but only 2, the ones that I was setting as background of a specific component.
 The codeline is the following:

```
<body [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + '../../img/image1.jpg' + ') no-repeat fixed center' }">


<div class="panel col-lg-12" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + '../../img/image2.jpg' + ') repeat-x center'}">
```

I tried to set it on the css file without ngStyle and it did not work either. It works fine on ng serve, but it does not work when I try ng build.

Also, I am having another problem with ng build. Whenever I try to F5 a page it does not recognize the path. It works fine if I click on the links and it does redirect to other pages, but when I try to type the address on the url bar it does not work (except for the home address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, Images are not there inside **dist** folder which generated by **ng build**. Please check this **dist** folder. I think, this is still **bug** there. If it is true, then try to copy and paste that **public** folder in dist directory.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! It did work. I also managed to find another way to fix this problem. Apparently my angular-cli version was outdated (I installed it like 2 months ago), so I just updated it and it was able to recognize the image's directory.

Comment: Yep, I just tried to run it again and it did not work without copying the folder to the root directory, but if you do so it will work just fine. Thanks again for your help.